# What do you use newlisp for?

Tags: scripting, lisp, newlisp

Do you use newlisp? What have you used it for?

Comment: Probably the worst quality question I have ever seen.

Comment: Listen, I know that this question isn't very specific, nor is it really a programming question.  I am, however, curious to know how newlisp is viewed and used outside of its tiny ruelle of devotees.

Comment: Given how you already noticed that no one is asking/aswering questions about newlisp ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313988/why-arent-there-any-newlisp-questions-here-closed ), you might have guessed that few people here use it at all...

Comment: I use it to extract data from various text-based sources mostly using regular expressions.